# FileWriter and BufferedWriter imports are "conflicting" in JDK 7

Tags: java, file, io

I am using JDK 7 and I am trying to perform a simple write-to-file operation with the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter; // JAVA says this is conflicting...why?

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); // JAVA says this is an error and asks me to convert FileWriter to type Writer.
```

I am using JDK 7 and this is how I've always written to a file in Java, but this is the first in JDK 7, and it is not working.

Could someone please explain why?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Would you have another FileWriter class in the same package?

Comment: @Puce, 2 errors, it says import.java.io.FileWriter is conflicting with java.io.BufferedWriter and it's asking me to change FileWriter fw to Writer fw. HOwever, I have always thrown a FileWriter into BufferedWriter without problems. However, after upgrading to JDK 7, this is happening, so I would like to know why.

Comment: That's not the **exact** error message. Copy the message output by the compiler, and paste it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is that you have a class called FileWriter in the same package as the class, from which you've copied the code fragments. In that case, you are not allowed to import a FileWriter class from a different package, but have to use the qualified name (java.io.FileWriter) in the code itself.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake of naming my file 'FileWriter.java'...thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make the fw instance a `Writer`? e.g.

```
Writer fw = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

It is good practice to use the interface/abstractions rather than concrete implementations.

FileWriter inherits from OutputStreamWriter which inherits from Writer.

And more to the point the `BufferedWriter` constructor expects a `Writer` instance.

Comment: Did something change to enforce this new rule in JDK 7?

Comment: "BufferedWriter BW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("someFile.txt"));" works fine for me. Just to be sure, you have the IOException handling, right? ("try-catch" or "throws")